# resolved in async component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I had read the acticle [Client Data Fetching](https://ssr.vuejs.org/en/data.html#client-data-fetching) in Vue.js SSR

```
router.onReady(() => {
 // Add router hook for handling asyncData.
 // Doing it after initial route is resolved so that we don't double-fetch
 // the data that we already have. Using `router.beforeResolve()` so that all
 // async components are resolved.
 router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
 // ....
```

there is one statement says :

> Using `router.beforeResolve()` so that all async components are
> resolved

what is the meaning of "async components are resolved"?

Comment: It means that it will wait for any data loading via api or loading of any static files that are loaded asynchronously and once loaded the `router.beforeResolve()` is called

Comment: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-router-beforeresolve-with-asynchronous/11971/7